# Continuous Function Taking A Value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Does there exist a continuous function $f(x)$ such that it takes the value $0$ on a set with positive measure and is also not locally constant at any such point? If yes then please give an example and if no then how to prove this?

Comment: By "any such point", do you mean any point in the set of positive measure that you mentioned?

Comment: Yes at any point of that set having positive measure

Comment: Indeed such a function exists. For instance, let $F\subseteq[0,1]$ be a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) and $f(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,F)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee nice! why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem boils down to finding a [nowhere-dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set) closed set of positive measure. Indeed, if $F$ is such a set then $f(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x, F)$ will serve as an example to OP's question.

Now note that the [fat Cantor sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) satisfy those properties.